# Angular.extend $resource with functions for instances of $resource

Tags: angularjs, extend, angular-resource

I want to create a $saveOrUpdate function which will accept a success callback and I want to use that function on an instance of my $resource service, and not extend the service itself.

So, if I want to extend the service, I simply write something along these lines:

```
angular
    .module('company-registry.company')
    .factory('Company', Company);

Company.$inject = ['$resource'];
function Company($resource) {
    var companyService = $resource("https://api.mongolab.com/api...", { update: { method: 'PUT' } });

    angular.extend(companyService, {
        saveOrUpdate: function(company, successCallback) {...}
    });
    return companyService;
}
```

This creates the saveOrUpdate function on the actual service, but what I want is to have the following code work:

```
var company = new Company();
company.$saveOrUpdate(cb);
```

I have two questions here:

- since my $saveOrUpdate method will have to call $save or $update on my company, how do I reference the object on which the function is being called?
- How do I extend the methods available on the instances of my service?

Comment: what is `new Company()`?

Comment: My bad for not submitting the full code, "Company" is the name of the service. I'll add the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Company($resource) {
    var companyService = $resource("https://api.mongolab.com/api...", { update: { method: 'PUT' } });

    return angular.extend({
       "$saveOrUpdate":function(cb){
           ...
        }
     }, companyService);
}
```

**Edit: Changes made based on comment.** Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66z98qht/). Does this make more sense? The order of the object in `extend` method does matter. Depends on whether you want to add new properties to the existing object or create a new one by extending the other. You can self-reference the `Company` using `this` as shown in the example.

```js
return angular.extend({
        hello: function (text) {
            console.log(text);
            return text + " - OK";
        },
        saveOrUpdate: function (successCallback) {
            var response = this.hello("Foo Bar!");
            return successCallback(response);
        }
    }, companyService);
```

Comment: Could you explain this? I'm not sure how this extends the $resource instances available functions, nor do I see where I state which object should be saved or updated.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the question earlier. I have edited the answer. Does that help?

Comment: Other than changing the order of arguments in the angular.extend function, how does this differ from my code?

I want to have the $saveOrUpdate method available the same way I have the $save function available on $resource objects, and not to have this function the service level.
Also this doesn't answer how I can reference the company object in the $saveOrUpdate method.

Comment: Take a look at the example I made and see if that explains it better.